# How to use ForAll to prove things about functions?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Suppose I first declare:

```
$Assumptions = ForAll[{a,b}, b > a, f[b] > f[a]]
```

I (wrongly, as it turns out) assume that that this would cause

```
FullSimplify[f[4] > f[3]]
```

to evaluate to

```
True
```

but it does not (it just returns f[4] > f[3]). I've tried adding more to the assumptions i.e., that a & b are in reals, that for all x, f[x] is real and so on, but I'm just spitballing and these changes don't make a difference.

Comment: The documentation of Assumptions says: "The assumptions can be equations, inequalities, or domain specifications, or lists or logical combinations of these." I read this as implying ForAll is not included.

Comment: I see - thanks. Perhaps there is some other way to approach this? It certainly *seems* like the kind of thing Mathematica is more than capable of...

Comment: You could try setting an upvalue for f using UpSet or TagSet or their delayed versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of Assumptions says: "The assumptions can be equations, inequalities, or domain specifications, or lists or logical combinations of these." I read this as implying `ForAll` is not included.

An approach that seems to work is the following:

```
f[x_] > f[y_] ^:= Piecewise[{{True, x > y}}, False]

f[3] > f[4]

(* False *)

f[4] > f[3]

(* True *)
```

A probably better definition would be:

```
f[x_] > f[y_] ^:= x > y
```

Note that you'll have to make definitions for the other comparison functions (`GreaterEqual`, `Less`, `LessEqual`) as well, as the above only defines the `Greater` operator in relation to f.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `TransformationFunctions` if you don't want `f` evaluating outside of `FullSimplify`.

```
expr = f[4] > f[3];

mysimp[e_] := e /. {(Greater | GreaterEqual)[f[b_], f[a_]] /; b > a -> True, 
                    (Less | LessEqual)[f[b_], f[a_]] /; b < a -> True};

FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {mysimp, Automatic}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```